# I keep getting access to the path is denied when running a script on powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, shell

I know this question probably has been answered before.
I am running Powershell as admin. I am trying to output a command to a .txt file

Script: get-alias > C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Personal\Shell_Scripting\get_alias.txt

See error below: out-file : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Personal\Shell_Scripting\get_alias.txt'. At line:1 char:1

get-alias > C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Personal\Shell_Scripting\get_ali ...

- CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (:) [Out-File], DirectoryNotFoundException
- FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileOpenFailure,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutFileCommand

Comment: You are trying to pipe your results to that text file ?  ```C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Personal\Shell_Scripting\get_alias.txt``` exists and are you sure your ```get-alias``` will run from the location you are running that script? I bet if you path to script your problem will be resolved.

Comment: Try putting your output path (minus the file name) `C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Personal\Shell_Scripting` into an explorer window and see what happens. Better yet, go to the location and create a text file by hand, collect the full path and paste it below your current path. Your error states you have something wrong with it, an extra space maybe?

Comment: get-alias runs on the specified directory where I am running the script. I don't really know what you mean by path to script. When I past the file path on explorer it opens the file directory. I also tried Try putting your output path (minus the file name) and still got the same error